# How to decide Main Verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> The last thing we did was finish the supper.

What's the main verb in this sentence?  If it's 'was', then how do we treat 'did' & 'finish' here?

Comment: In a sentence like yours (one that contains a subordinate clause) the 'main' verb is the matrix (or upper) verb, i.e. the verb of the clause that _contains_ the subordinate clause. which in in this case is "was". "We did" and "finish the supper" are subordinate clauses, so neither of their verbs can be considered a 'main' verb.

Comment: Notice that 'main verb' is ill-defined; some contrast such with auxiliaries.

Comment: Here's a better way of looking at things: "be" is always an auxiliary, even when it's the only verb in the clause. More importantly, the term 'main verb' is misleading, since there is no contrast between 'main' verbs and auxiliary verbs. In your example, "did" and "finish" are thus just as much main verbs as "was" is; the only difference is that they head embedded subordinate clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Do you consider "to be" an auxiliary in the sentence "he is tall"?

Answer (score 0):

- The last thing we did was finish the supper.

The sentence you are trying to parse is of the type of those below (user LPH's bold type).

- The last thing **that** we want to do to the people who are looking for work **is to** disadvantage them by introducing policies such as the minimum wage and the social chapter. ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Parliamentary_Debates_Hansard/xblQAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+last+thing+that+we%22&dq=%22the+last+thing+that+we%22&printsec=frontcover))
- It wasn't easy to do, because the last thing **that** I wanted to do **was** cause you more pain. ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Last_Kings_2/mJ-yDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+last+thing+that+i%22&pg=PT26&printsec=frontcover))

> CoGEL, 1985: **15.15** […]
> The *to* of the infinitive is obligatorily absent when the infinitive clause is
> subject in these constructions, but it is optionally present when the clause is
> subject complement:
> ♦ What they must do is (to) propose an amendment to the resolution.

You can therefore rewrite the sentence this way ("(to) finish the supper" is a subject complement):

- The last thing **that** we did was **to** finish the supper.

The omission of "that" is usually considered to result in informal English, but not that of "to", which is merely optional.

Parsing is now easier.

- *The last thing was (to) finish the supper*: main clause ("reduced" subject)
- *The last thing (that) we did*: full subject of "*was*".
- *(to) finish the supper*: infinitive clause, subject complement introduced by the copula (was)
- *(that) we did*: restrictive relative clause with optionally omitted relative pronoun "that", the ("reduced") antecedent of "that" is "the last thing" (which is modified by this clause)

The main verb is therefore "to be".

Note: The modilication is RESTRICTIVE when the reference of the head is a member of a class which can be identified only through the modification that has bcen supplied. (CoGEL, **17.3**)

Comment: You have not answered the OP's question, which was concerned with identifying the 'main' verb in their example.

Comment: @BillJ Since I identify the main clause, its subject and its subject complement, the verb is deduced automatically (it is "was").